# Python pandas, select data by month

Tags: python, pandas

Does pandas have any function that can be used to select data that belongs to a certain month. If I would like data for January then based on the Series below it would be 4654.92 and 5922.55.

`2008-01-31    4654.921202
2008-02-29    4405.907331
2008-03-31    5277.126015
2008-04-30    3814.353624
2008-05-31     909.466583
2008-06-30     498.991260
2008-07-31      95.671703
2008-08-31      26.762731
2008-09-30     303.874072
2008-10-31    2219.250418
2008-11-30    3562.633841
2008-12-31    5669.641461
2009-01-31    5922.555024
2009-02-28    4990.197616`

Best Smail

Comment: You need only drop the day portion of the filter of that dupe.

Answer (score 0):

I would use datetime.strptime to parse the dateTime string into actual datetime.

Then you should be able to do:

```
df.loc[(df['date'].month==1)]
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)?